# Android: How to force the whole android device to be run on landscape only or portrait

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, lockscreen

Having problem to force the device to lock as landscape / portrait mode?

I created a launcher app which the activity itself was assigned screen orientation to be landscape, since my device was a landscape only device.

To further lock down the screen so when other application selected and run will be running in a landscape screen.

```
View orientationChanger = new LinearLayout(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams orientationLayout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    orientationLayout.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(orientationChanger, orientationLayout);
    orientationChanger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

It does do the trick e.g.

Now I want to allow user to rotate the orientation in case some application required to run in portrait mode.

```
I tried to run these command on adb shell before doing it on my code:

try {
        Process stopAccelerometer = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:accelerometer_rotation --bind value:i:0");
        Process toProtrait = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:3");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Yes it run the application in Portrait but if I applied a command to turn back to landscape it does move back to landscape.

```
            Process toProtrait = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:user_rotation --bind value:i:0");
```

In the code, the last value is 0 as landscape. I think the application itself doesn't support landscape so when I applied the command the app stayed at Portrait.

I found an application online which is doing just that.
 [Orientation Applications](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1412752)

Answer (score 0):

request the activity to landscape mode

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

request the activity to portrait mode

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

put it on your oncreate();

or just set it in your manifest activity

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait/landscape"
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Comment: I can't have slash in screenOrientation. It only allow either one option.